# what is nodereunner.exe,host controller.exe

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search

What is `noderunner.exe`,`host controller.exe` running under spfarm user under details of task manager of web front end server, and how these working for enterprise search and also I found noderunner.exe under search server.

Comment: Those are the processes which slow down the development environment !

Comment: Those are the processes that make all the search functionality work. If you are a dev AND you are not using search functions then set the service performance profile to REDUCED and you will see an improvement in performance of the other services.

Answer (score 0):

Noderunner.exe (Microsoft SharePoint Search Component) is a component of SharePoint 2013 Search managed by the SharePoint Search Host Controller Service, and each Noderunnerprocess hosts one of the following Search components;

- Crawl
- Content Processing
- Index
- Analytics
- Query Processing
- Search Administration

Noderunner.exe is the new executable of search service on SharePoint 2013. Each component having its own independent NodeRunner Process.

Read more here: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/noderunner-process-in-sharepoint-2013